# Parallelizing database access

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqldatareader

I create table with objects to process in SQL Server

The database is in dbserver.

Then, with a my app(c#), I use a `SqlDataReader` to iterate over all the object, and it makes it in time T. I use multithreading and mutex in my app and it use the same `SqlDataReader` for all the threads. I run in the serverp1.

Then to make it faster, I separate the object in 2 ranks or groups by a column.

Then I run the myapp in serverp01 for the objects in rank1 (`SqlDataReader` with a `select where rank = 1`) and then run the myapp in serverp02 for the object in rank2 (`SqlDataReader` with a `select where rank = 2`).

My issue is that it takes the same time T for both configs. May be I'm wrong but it should take T/2 time or close to it.

Somebody has an idea what its happening?

Comment: Have you looked at your SQL server to see if there are any issues there like blocking, waits etc?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're being bound by IO speed. When you run the thing on serverp1, are the CPU's maxed out? If not, then probably the network or the DB disks are the bottleneck. You can check the disk and network throughput on the DB server to see if they hit certain limit.

If the disk is the bottleneck, them try to make your table rows narrower, each row in your table should be as few bytes a possible. Make sure that the table you're querying only holds the few columns you actually need and that they're as compressed as possible (i.e. highly normalized with integer keys instead of varchar values, non nullable etc).

Remember that even when you only ask for a few columns, the whole page needs to be read from disk into memory. The more rows you can fit onto a page, the less pages the server needs to read.

If the network is the bottleneck, then only selecting the columns you need and making them as narrow (int key instead of varchar value) should be enough.

Regards GJ